# Implicit declaration of function 'UnityGetGLView' is invalid in C99

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, macos-catalina

I am trying to build a Unity build, but I get this error in xCode:

> [UnityGetGLView() addSubview: readerView];  **Bad receiver type 'int'**

I use MacOS Catalina 10.15.5; xCode 11.5

Please help!
What should I do?

```
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self];

    if (state) {
         [self performSelector: @selector(delayedActivate:) withObject: stateAsNumber
            afterDelay: 0.1];
    }
    else {
        [self delayedActivate: stateAsNumber];
    }
}

-(void) delayedActivate: NSNumber *) stateAsNumber
{
    BOOL state = [stateAsNumber boolValue];

    if (state) {
        if (!self.activated) {
            self.activated = TRUE;
            readerView = [[ICadeReaderView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
            [UnityGetGLView() addSubview: readerView]; // ERROR: Bad receiver type 'int'
            readerView.active= YES;
            readerView.delegate = self;
            readerView.hidden = NO;

            #if !__has_feature(obj_arc)
            [readerView release];
            #endif
        }
    }
    else {
        if (self.activated) {
            self.activated = FALSE;
            [readerView removeFromSuperview];
            readerView.active = NO;
            readerView.delegate = nil;
            readerView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post images of code or errors. Copy&paste them here as **text** and format them via the `{ }` button

Comment: I have found this thread, but I don't understand what to do exactly 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/incontrol-xcode-build-error-icademanager.823305/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it

Get the latest version of InControl. That code has been updated already. Make sure you delete InControl entirely before importing the latest version. Then also make sure you do a completely new build in Unity so that no old files remain in the Xcode project.

Make a backup of your project first. Then, in your Assets folder should be an InControl folder. Delete that. Then go to the Asset Store (or Package Manager, depending on Unity version) and find InControl, update and import it.